# Identifying French coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-system, openstreetmap, france

I'm having issues identifying the GPS system they used on this website : https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/itineraires-de-randonnee-dans-openstreetmap/

Data looks like this :

> 804572.9409005984 6112380.026752339

Some data also has negatives like this :

> -178481.5674790051 5360282.4944811445

The city it's supposed to aim close to is : `Soultzbach les Bains` and it's GPS coordinates are :

> 48.03657232207706, 7.2014655322229375

The closest to it I've been able to get is with `Lambert 3 sud` but it's still not accurate.
I've used this website : https://tool-online.com/conversion-coordonnees.php

Which system is this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you download the Shapefile dataset and open the `.prj` file, you'll see :

```
PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
...
, AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
```

This is the WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator -- Spherical Mercator, Google Maps, OpenStreetMap, Bing, ArcGIS, ESRI

See here : https://epsg.io/3857

An other indication was on the WMS / WFS layer, if you go on the help page :

[image]

And talking about your coordinates, `804572.9409005984 6112380.026752339` are indeed near `Soultzbach-les-Bains` in the North-East, and `-178481.5674790051 5360282.4944811445` near `Saint-Ignace` in the South-West.

Comment: Thank you!I figured the answer with the JSON format file which gave the correct EPSG